# How to set reducer name when using redux-act

Tags: redux

I'm playing with [redux-act](https://github.com/pauldijou/redux-act). I've created reducer using `createReducer`, and connected it to normal store just like normal plain reducer.

I wasnt able to get value from state at the beginning, but I realized that it's actually added as `reduce` to the state.

Am I missing something, should't be named as function name (which is `testState`)?

```
export const setTestState = createAction("Set test state");

const testState = createReducer(
  {
    [setTestState]: (state, payload) =>
      payload ? { ...payload, active: true } : null
  },
  null
);

// combined with others
createStore(combineReducers({...others, testState}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be `testState` indeed and looks like it is when I try to reproduce... [Check this code](https://codesandbox.io/s/6xq5637q7n)